# sendgrid mail not working on centos server

Tags: django

I have configured sendgrid mail on django project and it works fine in local server, but when I deployed on centos server on digital ocean it is not sending any mail, hope some body can help me. Mail setting as follows.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'usr'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pwd'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Check your Django logs to see if there is an error happening on your side, and also check the sendgrid account activity to see if the messages are being rejected for some reason.

Comment: I have a similar issue.